# MSSQL 2008 SP pagination and count number of total records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

In my SP I have the following:

```
with Paging(RowNo, ID, Name, TotalOccurrences) as 
(
    ROW_NUMBER() over (order by TotalOccurrences desc) as RowNo, V.ID, V.Name, R.TotalOccurrences FROM dbo.Videos V INNER JOIN .... 
)
SELECT * FROM Paging WHERE RowNo BETWEEN 1 and 50
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Paging
```

The result is that I get the error: invalid object name 'Paging'.
Can I query again the Paging table? I don't want to include the count for all results as a new column ... I would prefer to return as another data set. Is that possible?

Thanks, Radu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more research I fond another way of doing this:

```
with Paging(RowNo, ID, Name, TotalOccurrences) AS
(
    ROW_NUMBER() over (order by TotalOccurrences desc) as RowNo, V.ID, V.Name,    R.TotalOccurrences FROM dbo.Videos V INNER JOIN .... 
)
select  RowNo, ID, Name, TotalOccurrences, (select COUNT(*) from Paging) as TotalResults  from Paging where RowNo between (@PageNumber - 1 )* @PageSize + 1 and @PageNumber * @PageSize;
```

I think that this has better performance than calling two times the query.

Comment: This is not the fastest, i'm spending a lot of time working on this now.  The fastest solution is to do get a RowNo, and also a ReverseRowNo (opposite ordering), and then caculate the Total by doing "TotalRecords = RowNo + ReverseRowNo - 1".  Try it on a large dataset -- massive improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that because the CTE you are defining will only be available to the FIRST query that appears after it's been defined. So when you run the COUNT(*) query, the CTE is no longer available to reference. That's just a limitation of CTEs.

So to do the COUNT as a separate step, you'd need to not use the CTE and instead use the full query to COUNT on.
Or, you could wrap the CTE up in an inline table valued function and use that instead, to save repeating the main query, something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufnExample() 
    RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
with Paging(RowNo, ID, Name, TotalOccurrences) as 
(
    ROW_NUMBER() over (order by TotalOccurrences desc) as RowNo, V.ID, V.Name, R.TotalOccurrences FROM dbo.Videos V INNER JOIN .... 
)
SELECT * FROM Paging
)

SELECT * FROM dbo.ufnExample() x WHERE RowNo BETWEEN 1 AND 50
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.ufnExample() x
```

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that Radu D's solution's query plan shows double hits to those tables. It is doing two executions under the covers. However, this still may be the best way as I haven't found a truly scalable 1-query design.

A less scalable 1-query design is to dump a completed ordered list into a @tablevariable , SELECT @@ROWCOUNT to get the full count, and select from @tablevariable where row number between X and Y. This works well for <10000 rows, but with results in the millions of rows, populating that @tablevariable gets expensive.

A hybrid approach is to populate this temp/variable up to 10000 rows. If not all 10000 rows are filled up, you're set. If 10000 rows are filled up, you'll need to rerun  the search to get the full count. This works well if most of your queries return well under 10000 rows. The 10000 limit is a rough approximation, you can play around with this threshold for your case.

Comment: Avoid using temp tables or table variables to make queries on large datasets very fast.  You can still accomplish getting the TotCount without having to do a temp table, see my other comment.

Answer (score 0):

Write "AS" after the CTE table name Paging as below:
with Paging AS (RowNo, ID, Name, TotalOccurrences) as
( 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (order by TotalOccurrences desc) as RowNo, V.ID, V.Name, R.TotalOccurrences FROM dbo.Videos V INNER JOIN ....
) 
SELECT * FROM Paging WHERE RowNo BETWEEN 1 and 50 
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Paging